# I need a regular expression for the following

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for the following string format

NN-NNNN
where N is a single digit between 0 and 9

And the '-' is always there.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This one is extremely simple. If you look into any of the million "regex getting started" guides, you should be able to solve this yourself in less than 5 mins.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be:

```
^\d\d-\d\d\d\d$
```

or:

```
^\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

Of course, this means your input only EVER consists of this.

Comment: +1, The answer I wanted to give.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is it. I only EVER have this input in the field, if it is any different it is a wrong input

Comment: @user280139 In c# \d is not only 0-9, it includes all unicode code points that has the property "digit" (means e.g. Chinese numbers, ...), most of the time not a problem, but you need to know it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: This one is more compatible than `\d` version

Comment: @Shiplu `\d` is quite common and c# is supporting it. What would be an argument is that, in c# `\d` is not only 0-9 in fact it has all unicode code points that has the property "digit"

Comment: Whats worse, this one is wrong its missing anchors, that means it will also match "12345-1234567890".